# c++ detect if the client closed the connection (multi sockets)

Tags: c++, sockets, connection

In my program I have several sockets on the server. Each socket has its own port. I tried to detect if the client closed the connection with:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, sig_pipe);
```

But I have the problem that I don't know on which socket the connection was closed.
Is there some method to get it to know?

More about code:
In main program I started 3 Sockets on different ports. Accept, receive and send for each socket I put in one thread. So I have 3 threads at the end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should setup `SIGPIPE` to be ignored (see [`sigaction(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)) and handle `EPIPE` error code from [`write(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) and the likes.

Note, that reading zero bytes from TCP socket is the real indication of the other side closing the connection.

Comment: I use "send"-command, but I can also handle EPIPE error with "send" command. http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Sending-Data.html Thank you

Comment: Yes, that's what "and the likes" meant :)